# Firebase Cloud Functions re-deploy Error: could not handle the request (when using firestore and googleapis)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-api-nodejs-client

I have a Firebase Cloud Function becomes unreachabe for about 30 seconds after *every* time it is *re-deployed*. During the 30 seconds, it returns **500** `Error: could not handle the request`. After about 30 seconds, it functions normally.

I have reduced the function to a simple example that reproduces the error. The error seems to occur when `googleapis` is required *and* the function makes a query into firestore. **Removing the `googleapis` require statement *or* the firestore query eliminates the error.**

Is googleapis or firebase-admin not compatible with cloud functions? How can I write a function that uses both?

**index.js**

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const pack = require('./package.json');
const {google} = require('googleapis');

admin.initializeApp();

const app = express();
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  const name = req.body.name || 'unknown';

  admin.firestore().doc('settings/doesnotexist').get()
    .then(ref => {
      res.send({
        message: `Hello ${name}. Exists: ${ref.exists}`,
        version: pack.version,
      });
    });
});

exports.testDeployCody = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "version": "0.1.56",
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions:testDeployCody",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "firebase-admin": "^5.12.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^1.1.0",
    "googleapis": "^30.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-tools": "^3.19.1"
  }
}
```

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Deploy the cloud function (I use `npm run deploy`)
2. Test the function works via HTTPS
3. Increment the package.json version
4. Re-deploy the function
5. After the firebase tools says `Deploy Complete!`, test the function repeatedly via HTTPS to see the error message

Comment: Please file a bug report with the steps to reproduce the error. along with observations.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: I found the same behaviour. I believe that if you are requiring a bit heavy libraries then it takes about 30 seconds to get back to normal but if your function is as simple as "helloworld" then it works perfectly fine as soon as we deploy it.

Comment: mark922 I agree that it appears to be related to dependencies. I would be fine if it takes a long time for the new version to start, as long as the old version still runs. What I can't have is a service that occasionally returns 500 errors :-( Seems like an issue in the runtime...

Comment: Doug, bug report filed.

Comment: Does using service account credentials to init the firebase admin sdk mitigate this problem? As shown in last part of https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env